# Set supergloabal variable in class or not?

Tags: php, class, oop, post, setter

Got a simple function inside class that initializes message variable, setting POST value to it. Is there any point of setting it since $_POST will be available anywhere in the class anyway..? Does this raises any security concerns?

```
function set_posted_data(){
    $this->message = $_POST["message"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this slightly different. Regrettably I have no idea what your class looks like, so I have to make some guesses. First of all I would always start with a general function:

```
public function setMessage($message) {
    $this->message = $message;
}
```

So you can still use the class, even when the message isn't posted. Now normally I would set the posted value like this:

```
myclass.setMessage($_POST["message"]);
```

So, I wouldn't be using superglobals in the class at all. I would normally surround this with some checks, so only valid messages are accepted. Here's where I run into problems: I have no idea what to do here, because I don't know anything about your code. But checking the length could be useful, and maybe HTML code is not allowed, etc. General checks can be incorporated in the class, for instance, no HTML:

```
public function setMessage($message) {
    $this->message = strip_tags($message);
}
```

I would process all the posted parameters, and do all specific checks, more-or-less together. That makes it easier to check if the code is secure.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is better to do it the way you show, there is a few reasons for that:

- if in the future you will change it to $_GET, or the key "message" is changed or you get this data in whatever other way, you will just change it in this ONE place
- you can sanitize it here and if you change the way you want it sanitized, you will change it also only here

Answer (score 1):

I prefer injection for everything but the top level of functions. (i.e. `$class->function($_POST['val'])` The reason injection is preferable

- The more abstract you get downstream, the more you can reuse your code
- You don't have to go digging through your code every time you change a variable. All you change is the injection point